# is 121 divides the my pattern for base 2?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is $121|2^{120}-1$? If yes, is there any online free calculation to check these type of values?

Advanced thanks to one and all!
-Richard Sieman

Comment: ``Prelude> 2^120 `mod` 121`` gives $56$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $ \phi(121) = 110$, we know that $ 2^{110} \equiv 1 \pmod{121}$ by Euler's Theorem.

Hence, $2^{120} \equiv 2^{10} \equiv 1024 \equiv 56 \pmod{121}$, and thus $ 2^{120} -1\equiv 55 \pmod{121}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is prime, then you have $p$ divides $2^{p-1} - 1$ by Fermat's little theorem, which would show that your result holds if $121$ is prime. However you have that $121 = 11^2$ is not prime, so it's more complicated. A simple calculation shows that the congruence indeed does not hold.

Comment: user2566092! here 121, can I call it as Fermat Pseudo prime?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your expression as$$2^{120}-1\\=(2^{60}+1)(2^{60}-1)\\=(2^{60}+1)(2^{30}+1)(2^{30}-1)\\=(2^{60}+1)(2^{30}+1)(2^{15}+1)(2^{15}-1)$$
so $$2^{120}-1\pmod{ 121}\\\equiv(2^{60}+1)(2^{30}+1)(2^{15}+1)(2^{15}-1)\pmod{ 121}$$
but since $2^{15}-1=32767 \equiv 97 \pmod{ 121}$
$$2^{120}-1\pmod{ 121}\\\equiv(2^{60}+1)(2^{30}+1)(2^{15}+1)(2^{15}-1)\pmod{ 121}\\\equiv(2^{60}+1)(2^{30}+1)\cdot97\cdot99\pmod{ 121}\\\equiv(2^{60}+1)\cdot44\cdot46\pmod{ 121}\\\equiv90\cdot88\pmod{ 121}\\\equiv55\pmod{ 121}$$